# LINQ2SQL installed but LINQ To SQL Classes missing from "Add New Item" list in Class Library Project

Tags: linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2017

I have VS 2017 Solution with Linq2SQL projects (with .dbml) files in them. When I add a new Class Library to the solution, and do an "Add New Item" in that project, the Linq To SQL Classes option is missing. It is present if I click on other projects in the solution. How do I add new LINQ To SQL Classes to my new Class Library project?

Comment: I had the same issue but changing the .net version to 5 solved it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So of course just a few minutes after I post this question I'm crawling through raw, unloaded Project files and realize I had added a "Class Library (.NET Standard)" instead of a "Class Library (.NET Framework)". The missing classes are available in (.NET Framework).

Comment: I'd almost downvote myself on this questions but I spent over an hour chasing my tail on this one, and maybe someone else is going to run into the same thing.

Comment: I didn't get this. Can someone elaboratee?

Comment: Found it. Jesus this was huge trouble. Just a simple misplacement

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you haven't installed this component yet. It's best to install it this way:

Open **Visual Installer** and go to:
**-> More -> Modify**

After appear Modify window click on Individual Components tab. Then in the **Code tools** category check **LINQ to SQL tools** and install it.